# Get the longest common string prefix of all words in a list

Tags: python, stemming

Is there a function that returns the (length of the) longest string that all values start with in a list:

```
["flexible","flexile","flexion","flexor"]
```

Should return: `"flex"` or 4

And for this: `["flexible","flexile","flexion","flexor","ape"]`, it should return an empty string or 0;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.commonprefix(["flexible","flexile","flexion","flexor"])
'flex'
```

Comment: Surprising use case, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any iterables:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def commonprefix(xs):
  return map(lambda xs: xs[0],takewhile(lambda xs: len(set(xs)) == 1,zip(*xs)))

print len(commonprefix(["flexible","flexile","flexion","flexor"])) # 4
print len(commonprefix(["flexible","flexile","flexion","flexor","ape"])) # 0
```